What’s the Hopf dual of quantum supergroup Uq(gl(m|n))
My problem is if $GL_q(m|n)$ and $U_q(gl(m|n))$ are Hopf dual to each other, and if they are dual, if there are some references.
I ask this question because I saw an example in Kassel’s book: $GTM155$ quantum group, in section 7 of part V. where he given a Hopf duality between $U(sl_2)$ and $SL(2)$. And I am consider a problem about Schur-Weyl duality of $U_q(gl(m|n))$ recently, I want to first consider it’s Hopf duality.
Thank you for any comments about this problem.
